# Duplicated product not showing on front-end, Magento 2.3.2

Tags: product, magento2.3, frontend, bug, duplicate

I have upgraded my Magento EE store from 2.2.7 to 2.3.2, and the issue I am facing is, **after duplicating a product, the duplicated product is not showing on frontend**.

The urls are generating, product qty is set, enabled, in stock, set enabled in website mode also, ran indexing but not helpful.

However new products are creating and also coming on frontend.

Any guesses or workarounds?

Comment: Confirm that you are set product as "In stock".

Comment: Yes product is set to be "in stock" also.

Comment: Check if it has different values in Store View.

Comment: Yes, it was also set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved now. Some products weren't showing because of their migrated attributes. Matched them with the products that were working and now resolved